# Really basic AJAX about requesting a response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on a Scrabble question and to verify if the words exist in my language I am trying to use the wordreference api: http://www.wordreference.com/docs/api.aspx.

This is what kind of response it returns when accessing a word that doesn't exist

1.

```
{
    "Response" : "Redirect",
    "URL" : "/enro/umbrella"
}
```

2.

```
{"Error" : "NoTranslation", "Note" : "No translation was found for umbrellaasd."}
```

My question is what do I put inside the success function below to see if the word exists or not?

```
function exista(word) {
    var ok = 0;
    var raspuns;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "http://api.wordreference.com/0.8/ff175/json/roen/" + word,
        method: 'get',
        success: function(transport) {
        }

     });
    return ok;
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Don't use `async: false` unless you absolutely have to, which is almost never.

Comment: You can have a callback to `exista`, like `function exista(word, callback){` and then call that from your success handler to do the rest like `success: function() { /* ... */ callback(); }`

Comment: Agree with @techfoobar if you think you need it, you're probably not writing good JS. The success callback will help but a modern alternative using jQuery would be to use deffered objects. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: If you think you need `async: false` you're not dealing with asynchronousness in the right way. `async: false` will **block your entire script**, this also means all other event handlers like clicks and onkeydowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transport` is an object representing the server's response, so you should be able to test for `transport.Error` and/or `transport.Response` to distinguish error and success responses.

Comment: transport.Response returns undefined for the word umbrella. I have no idea why.

Comment: try adding `dataType: "json"` to the request properties - api.wordreference.com doesn't set the correct Content-Type for its responses.